# How to replace content of nested files?

Tags: shell, find, file-copy, busybox

I need to find all `project.updated` files in some nested directory and use these files for content replacement of `project.json` file in the **same** directory.

I'm using BusyBox (1.33.1).

```
/apps
    /project1
        project.json
        project.updated
    /project2
        project.json
```

As you can see, there is a `project.updated` file in the project1 folder. The content of this file should replace `project.json` file.

This is only working, if I know the exact file:

```
cat /apps/project1/project.updated > /apps/project1/project.json
```

How do I do this in a dynamic way as there are many projects and only a few of them have an `project.updated` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` and `-execdir` which executes the given command in the directory where the file is found:

```
find /apps -type f -name '*updated'\
-execdir bash -c 'cat "$0" > "$(basename "$0" .updated).json"' {} \;
```

For a dry-run, just `echo` the command first and maybe print the found file:

```
find /apps -type f -name '*updated' -print\
-execdir bash -c 'echo cat "$0" \> "$(basename "$0" .updated).json"' {} \;
```

**Please do not forget to escape the redirection here `\>`!**

(works with `sh`, too and is POSIX-compliant, if you need it portable)

---

If `-execdir` is not available, `-exec` will do, but one needs to define the `dirname` of the target file, too:

```
find /apps -type f -name '*updated'\
-exec bash -c 'cat "$0" > "$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0" .updated).json"' {} \;
```

Or simpler, but not avaialable in `sh`:

```
find /apps -type f -name '*updated'\
-exec bash -c 'cat "$0" > "${0/%updated/json}"' {} \;
```

Where `${0/%updated/json}` matches `updated` at the END of string `$0` and replaces it with `json`. Since `$0` contains the whole path as the result from `find`, `-execdir` is not necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed to post the information, that I'm using BusyBox. There I do get the error `find: unrecognized: -execdir`

Comment: @user3142695 updated with alternatives